# Replace Variable in URL onClick

Tags: javascript

Want to replace the varaible after 'sku=' in the src= using onClick, then reload the iframe.

```
<iframe id="preview" src="//preview.domain.com/?sku=100-1&amp;month=May"></iframe>

<div class="smr-three">
<button id="smrone" onclick="smrclickone()">test1</button>
<button id="smrtwo" onclick="smrclicktwo()">test2</button>
<button id="smrthree" onclick="smrclickthree()">test3</button>
<script>
function('smrclickone') {
    document.getElementById('preview').src = document.getElementById('preview').src.replace('sku','100-1')
};
function('smrclicktwo') {
    document.getElementById('preview').src = document.getElementById('preview').src.replace('sku','100-2')
};
function('smrclickthree') {
    document.getElementById('preview').src = document.getElementById('preview').src.replace('sku','100-3')
};
</script>
```

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific and tell what is wrong with your code, show a `console.log()` or something?

Comment: Nothing happens when I click on the buttons, its not finding the 'sku' variable and replacing with the 100-1, 100-2, or 100-3

Comment: Not sure where you learned how to declare functions that way, but that is wrong an why it does not work. `function('smrclickone') {` should be `function smrclickone() {`

Comment: Thanks @epascarello that was my hold up, I copy/pasted/edited things so many times I did not catch that I wasnt even declaring the function correctly. Had a few other errors that were corrected, will post the finished product

Answer (score 1):

This is simpler:

```js
var baseUrl = "//preview.domain.com/?month=May";
window.onload=function() {
  document.querySelector(".smr-three").onclick=function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName=="BUTTON") {
      document.getElementById('preview').src = baseUrl+"&sku="+this.getAttribute("data-sku");
    }
  }
}
```

using

```html
<iframe id="preview" src="//preview.domain.com/?sku=100-1&amp;month=May"></iframe>

<div class="smr-three">
  <button type="button" id="smrone"   data-sku="100-1">test1</button>
  <button type="button" id="smrtwo"   data-sku="100-2">test2</button>
  <button type="button" id="smrthree" data-sku="100-3">test3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace does not do what you think here. This function can be used to update GET parameters in a URL:

```
function updateURLParameter(url, param, paramVal) {
    var newAdditionalURL = "";
    var tempArray = url.split("?");
    var baseURL = tempArray[0];
    var additionalURL = tempArray[1];
    var temp = "";
    if (additionalURL) {
        tempArray = additionalURL.split("&");
        for (var i=0; i<tempArray.length; i++){
            if(tempArray[i].split('=')[0] != param){
                newAdditionalURL += temp + tempArray[i];
                temp = "&";
            }
        }
    }

    var rows_txt = temp + "" + param + "=" + paramVal;
    return baseURL + "?" + newAdditionalURL + rows_txt;
}
```

Use that on your URL the following way:

```js
let preview = document.getElementById('preview')

function smrclickone() {
  preview.src = updateURLParameter(preview.src, "sku", "100-1");
  console.log(preview.src)
};

function smrclicktwo() {
  preview.src = updateURLParameter(preview.src, "sku", "100-2");
  console.log(preview.src)

};

function smrclickthree() {
  preview.src = updateURLParameter(preview.src, "sku", "100-3");
  console.log(preview.src)

};


function updateURLParameter(url, param, paramVal) {
  var newAdditionalURL = "";
  var tempArray = url.split("?");
  var baseURL = tempArray[0];
  var additionalURL = tempArray[1];
  var temp = "";
  if (additionalURL) {
    tempArray = additionalURL.split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
      if (tempArray[i].split('=')[0] != param) {
        newAdditionalURL += temp + tempArray[i];
        temp = "&";
      }
    }
  }

  var rows_txt = temp + "" + param + "=" + paramVal;
  return baseURL + "?" + newAdditionalURL + rows_txt;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="preview" src="//preview.domain.com/?sku=100-1&month=May"></iframe>

<div class="smr-three">
  <button id="smrone" onclick="smrclickone()">test1</button>
  <button id="smrtwo" onclick="smrclicktwo()">test2</button>
  <button id="smrthree" onclick="smrclickthree()">test3</button>
```

Comment: Right, looks like a lot, it's reusable though, so yay?